# Apply group of functions by ID across 2 datasets - one with single observation per ID, the other with multiple observations per ID

Tags: r, apply

I have a question about the best way to use the apply group of functions.

I've got 2 datasets tied to an ID. One dataset is weekly, so there are 52 weeks.

I want to apply a function that takes 52 weeks of data, and does a transformation based on 1 parameter.

How can I use the Apply groups of functions to do this?

Weekly Data: ID = 1,2..., Time= 1 - 52
Transformation Parameter: ID = 1,2,...

Suppose transformation function is:

```
xtransformation = function(w,x){
xtransformation  = w*x
}
```

Where w is 52 weeks of weekly data, x is the transformation parameter.

I guess what I'm asking is, how do I use the apply group of functions with by an ID, across 2 datasets, when one dataset has multiple observations for each ID in the group and the other just has 1 observation per ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

1- merge the 2 data sets per ID

2- apply the the function per group of ID

Here an example using `data.table` for sugar-syntax:

```
## data.table with multiple observations per ID
dx1 <- data.table(w=1:9,
                 ID=rep(1:3,each=3))
## data.table with single observation per ID
dx2 <- data.table(x=1:3,
                  ID=1:3)
merge(dx1,dx2)[,new:=w*x]
```